# spring boot exception controller example

Tags: java, spring

I'd like to handle error response on spring boot.

here's my default error response for not found error.

```
{
"timestamp": "2020-12-09T02:37:03.698+00:00",
"status": 404,
"error": "Not Found",
"message": "",
"path": "/v1.0/test"}
```

I tried to catch it on my custom error handle controller but doesn't work.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${server.error.path:${error.path:/error}}")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionController {

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExceptionController.class);
private final BaseEntityVo baseEntityVo;

//uri not found
@ExceptionHandler({NoHandlerFoundException.class})
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public BaseEntityVo notFoundException(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest){
baseEntityVo.setError(ErrorConstant.SC_2007_URI_NOT_FOUND_ERROR.toString(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI()));
return baseEntityVo;
}
```

how to handle 404, 405, 415, 500 , and default error?

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of the Spring `DispatcherServlet` is not to throw a `NoHandlerFoundException` where there is no handler found, it handles the response itself. You should be able to catch other exceptions with the above method but if you want to provide your own 404 responses you need to initialise the DispatcherServlet with `throwExceptionIfNoHandlerFound`.